# Binary file read write

Tags: c#, binary

OK I have a binary file that needs to be able to read and then write to from csv data.

I have about 12k records that needs to converted from csv to binary, This hard for me to wrap my head around it personally. Any help would be appreciated. C# with visual studio is what I am using.

This is the file that I am reading

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            310         KEITH                                   SFGEH6                                                                          BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        å¤_                    š™ÏA                                                                                   310         KEITH                                   OSAD                                    SDNVCS                                  BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        ¤_                      B                                                                                   310         57I M4                                  8M4M8                                   8M                                      BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        ?¤_                      8A                                                                                   310         WERTHWR                                 SFGHERH                                                                         BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        À¤_                      B                                                                                   310         HMDFGH                                  ADGNBSFDGNFS                                                                    BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        ö¤_                      LB                                                                                   310         GHMNDGMH                                SFMSFGHMNS                                                                      BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        Â¤_                      8B                                                                                   310         FGSXFDGH                                SDGHSDHG                                                                        BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        þ$¤_                      ˜A                                                                                   310         HTAH                                    AFGHBADF                                                                        BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        &¤_                      ÈA                                                                                   310         ADHAD                                   ADGH                                                                            BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        ©)¤_                      |B                                                                                   310         TYDJU                                   DGTJ                                                                            BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        &*¤_                      °B                                                                                   310         E57IE5                                  ETUI                                                                            BRENTWOOD                               CA 90049                                                                                                                                                                        J,¤_                    ÍÌ\@                                                                                   207                                                                                                                                 TOP                                     ME 04011
```

and this is the structure I am told.
Each record has the following structure:
#define DELIVERY_MAX_HISTORY 6

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct 
{
  char area_code[4];
    char phone[8];
    char name[40];
    char address1[40];
    char address2[40];
    char city[40];
    char state[3];
    char zip[13];
    char directions1[40];
    char directions2[40];
    char comment1[40];
    char comment2[40];
    unsigned long last_order_dates[DELIVERY_MAX_HISTORY];
    float last_order_totals[DELIVERY_MAX_HISTORY];
    short last_order_check_num[DELIVERY_MAX_HISTORY];
    char has_bad_checks;
    char ext[10];   // Currently only 4 bytes are allowed
    char Zone[10];  // not unused
    char extra[31];
 } delivery_data_type;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

OK so have put this together but I have no data output to the .bin file.
it just sits and run and runs

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\test\custdel.csv"))
        Console.WriteLine("DELIVERY Converter");
        var serializer = new BinarySerializer();
        using var csv = new CsvReader(Console.In, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var persons = csv.GetRecords<Person>();
        using var file = new FileStream("out.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(file, person);
        }
    }


    public class Person
    {
        [FieldOrder(0)]  // from BinarySerialization
        public string areacode { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(1)]
        public string phone { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(2)]
        public int name { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(3)]
        public string ddress1 { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(4)]
        public int address2 { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(5)]
        public string city { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(6)]
        public int state { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(7)]
        public string zip { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(8)]
        public int directions1 { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(9)]
        public string directions2 { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(10)]
        public int comment1 { get; set; }
        [FieldOrder(11)]
        public string comment2 { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(12)]
        public int has_bad_checks { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(13)]
        public string ext { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(14)]
        public int Zone { get; set; }
        [FieldOrder(15)]
        public string extra { get; set; }

       
    }
}
```

and this is the csv file

```
FieldOrder(0),FieldOrder(1),FieldOrder(2),FieldOrder(3),FieldOrder(4),FieldOrder(5),FieldOrder(6),FieldOrder(7),FieldOrder(8),FieldOrder(9),FieldOrder(10),FieldOrder(11),FieldOrder(12),FieldOrder(13),FieldOrder(14),FieldOrder(15)
```

207,207-210-2127,ADRIAN,160 COLUMBIA AVE,,BRUNSWICK,ME,4011,,,,,,,,
207,446-1989,ANNA,16 BRUNSWICK STATION,,BRUNSWICK,ME,,secondfloor,,,,,,,

ok I have found that problem and resolved and on to the next one.
Getting an error when debugging at the "foreach (var person in person)"
and this is what I am getting for the error
CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException: 'The conversion cannot be performed.
Text: 'name'
MemberType: System.Int32
TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.Int32Converter'
IReader state:
ColumnCount: 0
CurrentIndex: 2
HeaderRecord:

and my code change also and I removed the header from the csv file as I was getting another error on the headers:

```
 {

        Console.WriteLine("DELIVERY Converter");

        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = false,
        };

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\test\custdel.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
            var persons = csv.GetRecords<Person>();

            var serializer = new BinarySerializer();

            using var file = new FileStream("out.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            foreach (var person in persons)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(file, person);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your file is a type of flat file called a fixed-width file and what you're trying to is parse it. If you look on this site, you can find ways to do just that. You can also check NuGet for libraries that will do this for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
using BinarySerialization;
using CsvHelper;
...
    public class Person
    {
        [FieldOrder(0)]  // from BinarySerialization
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [FieldOrder(2)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var serializer = new BinarySerializer();
        using var csv = new CsvReader(Console.In, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var persons = csv.GetRecords<Person>();
        using var file = new FileStream("out.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(file, person);
        }
    }
```

It reads cvs from standard input and write binary representation to out.bin

See https://github.com/jefffhaynes/BinarySerializer and https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ for details

Example of file that you reading looks not like csv, so maybe you should consider something like https://github.com/mikeacjones/FixedWidthFileUtils to read file

Comment: I set tit up using your suggestion and I am still not getting it to work. I have edited my post with the new code and the csv file

Comment: Your CsvReader reads from `Console.In` instead of `StreamReader(@"c:\test\custdel.csv")`

Comment: Ok i am not understanding then. I need to replace the console.in with what "reader"?

Comment: I have made some changes and now can pull from the csv file but getting other errors. I edited my post to reflect this

Comment: Third field in file is "ADRIAN", but in class `Person` type of  `name` is `int`. "ADRIAN" could not be parsed as integer

Comment: that fixed that, but look at my output compared to they way it should be